# oracle apex application process PLSQL written to print reports using BLOB layouts stored in DB table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I use the Oracle Publisher solution for printing, I have oracle apex reports and queries written for them in shared components, the only different configuration from the usual configuration for printing (Oracle Publisher solution) that I have is that I keep my RTF layout files not in the apex itself but in the table that I have made myself. now I have encountered a problem and I don't know what is making it. When I wanna print my reports as pdf I see the error "invalid lob locator". now the one clue that I have is If I upload the RTF file in the APEX everything works fine and the printed pdf looks ok, but If I choose the "use generic report layout" in report query so the code in the application process would get the layout from the DB I see the "invalid lob locator" error.

the problem is not on the table because I've Checked It thousand times.
so the factor that is probably causing the problem is the PLSQL application process code that connects to DB and gets the layout and then sends the print command.

this is the code:

```
declare

    l_file_as_clob CLOB ;
    l_layout BLOB;
    l_asdsad CLOB;

    l_dest_offset integer := 1;
    l_src_offset integer := 1;
    l_lang_context integer := dbms_lob.default_lang_ctx;
    l_warning integer;
BEGIN


    select layout into l_layout
    from B5REPORTS
    where code = :APP_PRINT_LAYOUT_CODE
    AND APEX_APP_ALIAS = :APP_ALIAS 
    AND APEX_PAGE_ID = :APP_PAGE_ID ;

    dbms_lob.createtemporary(lob_loc => l_file_as_clob , cache => false);


    dbms_lob.converttoclob(
        dest_lob => l_file_as_clob
      , src_blob => l_layout
      , amount => dbms_lob.lobmaxsize
      , dest_offset => l_dest_offset
      , src_offset => l_src_offset
      , blob_csid => dbms_lob.default_csid
      , lang_context => l_lang_context
      , warning => l_warning);


    l_file_as_clob:= replace(l_file_as_clob,'+','%2B');
    l_file_as_clob:= replace(l_file_as_clob,'/','%2F');
    l_file_as_clob:= replace(l_file_as_clob,'=','%3D'); 


    --signature 2
    apex_util.download_print_document (
        p_file_name => :APP_PRINT_NAME
      , p_content_disposition => 'inline'
      , p_application_id => :APP_ID
      , p_report_query_name => :APP_PRINT_NAME
      , p_report_layout => l_file_as_clob
      , p_report_layout_type => 'rtf'
      , p_document_format => 'PDF'
    );

END;
```

and also this is the table which BLOBS(RTF layouts files)are stored in:

```
    ALTER TABLE FARA.B5REPORTS
ADD CONSTRAINT B5REPORTS_UK1 UNIQUE 
(
  CODE 
)
USING INDEX B5REPORTS_UK1
ENABLEALTER TABLE FARA.B5REPORTS
ADD CONSTRAINT B5REPORTS_PK PRIMARY KEY 
(
  ID 
)
USING INDEX B5REPORTS_PK
ENABLECREATE UNIQUE INDEX FARA.B5REPORTS_PK ON FARA.B5REPORTS (ID ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE APEX 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FARA.B5REPORTS_UK1 ON FARA.B5REPORTS (CODE ASC) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE APEX 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 2 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLELCREATE TABLE FARA.B5REPORTS 
(
  ID NUMBER NOT NULL 
, CODE VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, LAYOUT BLOB NOT NULL 
, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, NAME VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, APEX_APP_ALIAS VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, APEX_PAGE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE APEX 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOPARALLEL 
LOB (LAYOUT) STORE AS SYS_LOB0000103483C00003$$ 
( 
  ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW 
  CHUNK 8192 
  NOCACHE 
  LOGGING  
)
```

I'll add the picture of some sample data too.

I would Appreciate any comment, thought or anything because I'm really stuck here.Thanks IN Advance.:)[image]

Comment: I experienced this same problem in a prior project. I never found a resolution so I just have to upload a new RTF using the APEX app builder when the client wanbts to change their format.